# What is difference between firstWhere() and indexWhere() in Dart List

Tags: list, flutter, dart

I come across firstWhere() and indexWhere() while using List in Dart but it seems that these two have the same work. Is there any difference between them. And what is the use case for them??

Comment: `firstWhere` returns `List`'s element, `indexWhere` returns an integer index

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Documentation of both [firstWhere](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.4.1/dart-core/Iterable/firstWhere.html) and [indexWhere](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.4.1/dart-core/List/indexWhere.html) both state it clearly.

- firstWhere

> Returns the first element that satisfies the given predicate test.

- indexWhere

> Returns the first index in the list that satisfies the provided test.

The difference is that firstWhere returns the element while indexWhere return the index of the matched test.